# R multiple file "split and plot"

Tags: r, plot, split, r-factor

I have different csv file which I'm reading like this:

```
files <- list.files("D:/...", pattern = "L01")
for (x in files) {
  (assign(x, read.csv(x, head=TRUE,, sep=",", skip= 92)))
}
```

What I would like to achieve next is to split (assign the factors) the files according to a column named "Case" and plot for each of these "Case" all the mean value of the remaining  column in a bar plot. So at the end If I have 2 files, 50 factors and 26 column I will get 100 plot with 26 bar in it.

so I will need for each file something like,

```
Cases  <- factor(x$Cases)
```

But for each file and then 1 plot for each factor with 26 bar.

Hope this is clear.

Thanks for any suggestion.

E.g. for each file I have

```
AAA  col1   col2  col3   ....  
AAA             
BBB  
BBB         
CCC  
CCC    
DDD  
DDD    
EEE  
EEE    
AAA  
AAA     
BBB  
BBB      
CCC  
CCC    
DDD  
DDD    
EEE  
EEE
```

So the factors are `AAA`, `BBB`, `CCC`, `DDD`, `EEE`. I need to plot the mean of each column of these factor for each file.

Thanks for support.

Comment: Please provide an example of the csv input and output i.e. column headings and a few lines of data. Do the files have the same structure?

Comment: Yes, the files have the same structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not worded very clearly, but something like this might get you started:

```
# First, some sample data
set.seed(1)
df = data.frame(Cases = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 20, replace=TRUE),
                Set1 = sample(4:10, 20, replace=TRUE),
                Set2 = sample(6:19, 20, replace=TRUE),
                Set3 = sample(1:20, 20, replace=TRUE),
                Set4 = sample(5:16, 20, replace=TRUE))

# Use aggregate to find means by group
temp = aggregate(df[-1], by=list(df$Cases), mean)

# Plot
# par(mfrow=c(2, 2)) # Just for demonstration; used for the attached image
lapply(temp[-1], barplot, names.arg = temp$Group.1)
dev.off() # Reset the graphics device if you've changed par.
```

This gives you something like the following:

[image]

## Update

After reading your question again, I *think* that I misunderstood how you wanted to do your groupings. The following uses `apply` to plot by rows instead of columns.

```
par(mfrow=c(2, 3)) # Just for demonstration 
apply(temp[-1], 1, barplot)
dev.off() # Reset the graphics device
```

[image]

## Update [to answer some of the questions in comments]

If you want to combine some of the factors, I would suggest creating a new factor variable before splitting. So, for instance, if you wanted to split by "A+B", "C", "D", and "E" (four groups instead of five), you can do something like the following:

```
# Create a new factor variable
df$Cases_2 = df$Cases # So you don't overwrite your original data
levels(df$Cases_2) <- ifelse(levels(df$Cases_2) %in% c("A","B"),
                             "AB", levels(df$Cases_2))
# Proceed almost as before
temp = aggregate(df[-c(1, 6)], by=list(df$Cases_2), mean)
apply(temp[-1], 1, barplot)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Works really well. But I still have a couple of question. Let's say that I want to skip some columns in the barplot. How to achieve this?. The second one is: How to sum some of the factors together (e.g. AAA+BBB) and then plot them?. Thanks really a lot

Comment: Oups, surely we answered at the same time. (Sorry I just noticed your comment, not your answer -- here is my +1).

Comment: @g256, you can use basic subsetting to skip some of the columns. Using the example data I've provided, `apply(temp[-1][, -c(1, 4)], 1, barplot)` would drop `Set1` and `Set4`. Similarly `apply(temp[-1][, c(1, 4)], 1, barplot)` will plot *only* `Set1` and `Set4`.

Comment: @g256, when you say "sum some of the factors together ... and then plot them" do you mean to sum the means of those factors? What type of plot? Is this building on your original question or a totally new one?

Comment: @mrdwab I reformulate. I will need to sum together some of the factors e.g. (AAA+BBB) before plotting them in the same way. So in your example let's say the value coming from  letter A and B together. So at the end you will get 4 graph instead of five and one of these graph will have set1fromA+set1fromB then set2fromA+set2fromB and then  the mean. Hope this is clear. Thanks for your support.

Comment: @g256, See my update. I think this is what you're asking for.

Comment: This is what I was searching for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have your data frame set up correctly, how about using `aggregate` (or `ddply` from the [plyr](http://plyr.had.co.nz/) package)? Here is a toy example with one such data frame (you will need to embed this in your loop or write a custom function).

```
L01_001 <- data.frame(Cases=gl(5, 2, 5*2*2, labels=c("AAA","BBB","CCC","DDD","EEE")), 
                      replicate(3, rnorm(5*2*2)))
mean.by.case <- with(L01_001, aggregate(L01_001[,-1], list(Cases=Cases), mean))
## opar <- par(mfrow=c(nlevels(L01_001$Cases), 1))
## apply(mean.by.case[,-1], 1, function(x) barplot(x))
## par(opar)
library(lattice)
barchart(~ X1 + X2 + X3 | Cases, mean.by.case)
```

I would not recommend using bar charts for visualizing your data: they are incredibly bad at showing subtle variation in your data and have a poor [data-ink ratio](http://www.infovis-wiki.net/index.php/Data-Ink_Ratio). Cleveland's dot plot or level plot would do the job, in my opinion. In the later case, you can even represent everything on a single page, which looks like a pretty sound alternative to "100 plot with 26 bar in it."

Comment: +1 - I haven't used the `lattice` plots a lot. Is there an easy way to automate this part: `~ X1 + X2 + X3`. If I understand the OP correctly, this would have to be `~ X1 + X2 + ... + X49 + X50` (or whatever they have named their columns) for each of the two files.

Comment: By the way, I totally agree with your other suggestions and hopefully the OP takes you up on it, but small multiples can also sometimes be pretty effective if they are done correctly.

Comment: @mrdwab Sure, we won't type the whole formula by hand. Something like this should work: `fm <- as.formula(paste("~ ", paste(paste("X", 1:50, sep=""), collapse="+"), "| Cases")); barchart(fm, mean.by.case, xlab="")`.

Comment: thanks--I did not know about `as.formula` and had tried with just `paste` and it wasn't working out for me.

Comment: @chl Thanks for help. Btw the columns have specific different name so I cannot use something like `(paste("X", 1:50, sep="")`. Thanks for the advice. I'm still working on the layout in order to get the best graphic because as you already pointed out simply bar chart are not the best.